# Using bing enterprise api with bokeh instead of google api

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm working on developing some dashboards for my company that contain sensitive information, and therefore cannot allow google to gather information from their servers.  We have access to Bing enterprise maps which solves this problem, but I would like to develop my dashboards using Bokeh, which is setup to use google APIs. Has someone solved this problem and redirected Bokeh to Bing, or would I need to solve this problem myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh `0.12.16` there is no plot type currently built in that would use Bing maps. You coud write a [custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) but I will state up front that it would be a very involved effort. If you like, you can open a GitHub issue to discuss adding Bing maps support directly.